# How to Run a Script From Directory Structure When running Python Script in Both Linux and Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, scripting

1. I have a Python script that creates some GUI widgets and this explicitly was created in Linux and runs fine.
2. But I wanted to run the same script in Windows as well without much change. But the script has the following command call to another script to run from a particular directory.

   ```
   os.system('$PROOT/.loc_bin/run_loc.csh  %s %s' % (str(e_name), str(e_name_pkg),))
   ```
3. Wanted to make the above script call common, so that I can use the script to run both in Linux as well in windows.
4. I tried the below command, but faced syntax issues `"sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token "`. So wasn't sure if this is correct or not.

   ```
   os.system('os.path.join($PROOT/.loc_bin/run_loc.csh) %s %s' % (str(e_name), str(e_name_pkg),))
   ```

Any clue/idea on how to run this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do with `os.path.join()` - it shoudl be use as `join(folder, filename)` - so using it with single value makes no sense. There is nothing to join when you have only one value. And it can't be use inside `string` but `os.path.join() + " string"`.

Comment: First, why are you even trying to os.path.join within os.system? os.system runs a shell command and os.path.join is python, not shell. Secondly, windows doesn't have csh, so you need to port the script to a different langauge first.

Comment: maybe first test code in Windows with `/full/path/to/run_loc.csh` and later you may try to use variable `$PROOT` in shell or directly in Python `os.getenv('PROOT')` or put both directory directly in code and use `if sys.platform == 'win32: path="C:/..." else: path="/home/..."`